# Call a .NET method with part of the method name replaced by a variable

Tags: powershell, variable-substitution

Here is a simple command that I would like to use a variable in.

`(Get-Date).AddDays(-30)`

What I'm trying to do is substitute a variable $Time for the word Days.

`$Time="Days"` OR `$Time="Hours"`

Then run something like this:

`(Get-Date).Add$Time(-30)`

Is there a simple way to do this in 1 line?

Obviously I could write an If statement to do this but it seems like there should be a way to make this work in a single command.

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea, except you need to use the method name 100% from a string or not as a string.

You can do what you seek like this.

```
$Time = "Days"
(Get-Date)."Add$Time"(-30)
```

Or

```
$Time = "AddDays"
(Get-Date).$Time(-30)
```

Comment: Note: This works because the right side of the "." operator is considered an expression and evaluated as such.